# Locally euclidean 2D-surfaces

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, curvature

In most places, a Riemannian manifold is defined to be a locally euclidean surface (with other restrictions). When thinking of 2D-surfaces, this raises two questions:

1. Does locally euclidean mean locally flat (angles of triangle sum to 180 degrees), or just that it can be represented by a 2D coordinate system?
   Taking the example of a sphere *without poles*, both the sphere *without poles* and a tiny patch on it have a coordinate representation in R2. But only the small patch is (almost) flat. So which of the two properties are really locally euclidean? Or does one is a consequence of the other?
2. In 2D, a *regular surface* with a metric can be considered a Reimannian manifold. So what property of a regular surface makes it locally euclidean?

Comment: Have you actually seen general $2$-manifolds defined as "locally Euclidean", or just "locally modeled on $\mathbf{R}^{2}$"?

Comment: Yes. For instance this talks about a general n-manifold (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Manifold.html).

Comment: General manifolds do not have a notion of curvature and angles. You have to add that separately to make a Riemannian manifold. The "locally euclidean" part of general manifolds is purely topological.

Comment: @Arthur: Does the question read correctly now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$"Just that the manifold can be represented (locally) by an $n$-dimensional coordinate system."

   In the context of the [Mathworld definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Manifold.html) of smooth manifold, "locally Euclidean" might better be phrased "locally Cartesian": locally, the space is modeled on the smooth structure of $\Reals^{n}$.

   As Arthur says, a smooth manifold comes with no natural definitions of length, angle, or curvature.

   If a differential geometer speaks of a *locally-Euclidean manifold*, by contrast, it may well mean a [flat Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold), in which small geodesic triangles have total interior angle $\pi$. It's therefore potentially ambiguous to speak of "locally-Euclidean" in the context of Riemannian geometry.

   Incidentally, a Riemannian manifold is "pointwise Euclidean" in the sense that each tangent space comes equipped with a positive-definite inner product. Flatness, however, is a [differential condition on the metric components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor).
2. If $U \subset \Reals^{n}$ is a non-empty open set, a regular mapping $\Phi:U \to \Reals^{N}$ is an [immersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immersion_%28mathematics%29), and each point $x$ in $U$ has a neighborhood $V$ such that

   - $\Phi(V) \subset \Reals^{N}$ is a smooth $n$-manifold, and
   - $\Phi:V \to \Phi(V)$ is a diffeomorphism.

   The flat (Euclidean) metric on $\Reals^{N}$ pulls back to a Riemannian metric on $U$, but generally this metric is not flat.